# Make Css color value match color value of another css selector

Tags: jquery, css

This codepen will hopefully better explain my question.
https://codepen.io/MatteCrystal/pen/eYeaojj

The following 3 selectors can be found across 2 css files in my code. `mystyle.css` and another from a plugin i'm using, `plugin.css`

```css
/* plugin.css I don't want to mess with this */
.class-1{
  color:red;
}

/*mystyle.css below -----------*/
.class-1.class-2{
  color:purple;
}


.class-1.class-2.class-3{
  color: red; /*I don't want to explicitly code this value*/
}
```

if an element has all three classes I want it's color value to match what would be applied if it had just the `.class-1` style applied. However, the `.class-1` style is part of the css for the plugin I'm using. So if the plugin was updated in the future to make `.class-1` green for example then it would still appear red in my code if I hardcode the value red for `.class-1.class-2.class-3`

But I also don't want to override it by making a style like this in `mystyle.css`

```css
.class-1, .class-1.class-2.class-3{
  color:red;
}
```

If I used this code and the `plugin.css` color changed to green I would avoid the issue of `.class-1` and `.class-1.class-2.class-3` colors being out of sync but they would remain red.

I want to create css in the `mystyle.css` file that will make the color value of `.class-1.class-2.class-3` match the color value of `class-1`

### Is this possible?

CSS only solution is ideal but if there is a jquery solution It would also be welcome. In fact if both are possible I would prefer to see both solutions.

Comment: Could CSS variables solve your issue?

You could create variable
```css
* {
    --color: red;
}

.class-1.class-2.class-3{
  color: var(--red)
}
```

Comment: I don't think so because the only way I can think of for that to work is to add the css variable to both mystyle.css and plugin.css Meaning I will of made changes to plugin.css that won't be kept if the plugin has an update.